# How to use gdal_translate to transfer all 400 gcp's at once

Tags: python, gdal

With gdal_translate we can add GCP from one source to another source

```
gdal_translate -gcp pixel1 line1 X1 Y1 -gcp pixel2 line2 X2 Y2 ... source.tif sourceGCP.tif
gdalwarp -r bilinear -t_srs EPSG:xyz sourceGCP.tif sourceCRS.tif
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 sourceCRS.tif destCRS.tif
```

Writing 400 or even more GCP's the format is time-consuming, is there any wild card in which we can mention to translate all the GCP's from source to destination at once?

Comment: I think that adding GCP's to a clean tiff with -gcp parameters is the slow part. Using --optfile http://gdal.org/gdal_utilities.html can make it easier. Also using virtual VRT format for interim files http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html makes the process faster.

Comment: The GCP's are (only) defined in the first command. They are not taken from the source.tif. You don't have to enter GCP for every raster cell.

Comment: @AndreJ I have file a.tif which has 400 GCP's, now I have new file b.tif how do I transfer all the GCP's from a.tif to b.tif

Comment: I would try listgeo and geotiffcp http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/listgeo.html

Comment: If the extent is the same: Create a VRT file around it, and exchange the path to the tif.